# Why would a PreparedStatement with no input parameters succeed, but an identical version WITH input parameters fail?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I'm running the following code:

```
// Query without parameters
String query = "select data_source from Qc_data_blending_sources where external_object_type_name='well' AND instance_surrogate_key='837410' and attribute_name='preferred_latitude'";
PreparedStatement testPstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet testRs = testPstmt.executeQuery();
if(testRs.next()){
    System.out.println("Result: " + testRs.getString(1));
}

// Query with parameters
sources_query = new StringBuilder("select data_source from Qc_data_blending_sources where external_object_type_name=? AND instance_surrogate_key=? AND attribute_name=?");
sourcesPstmt = con.prepareStatement(sources_query.toString());
sourcesPstmt.setString(1, vo.getWellSurrogateKey()); //set to 837410
sourcesPstmt.setString(2, "well");
sourcesPstmt.setString(3, "preferred_latitude");

dataBlendingSources.append("Preferred latitude: ");
sourcesRs = sourcesPstmt.executeQuery();
if(sourcesRs.next()){
    dataBlendingSources.append(sourcesRs.getString(1) + " \n");
}
else{
    dataBlendingSources.append(" not found, \n");
    System.out.println("Preferred latitude not found. Query: " +
            sources_query.toString() +
            " \ninstance_surrogate_key: " + vo.getWellSurrogateKey() + 
            " attribute_name: preferred_latitude");
}
```

When I run it, it gives a valid result for the first query and says "preferred latitude not found" for the second one. What gives? What could be going on here?

Comment: Looks like you are setting param 2 to "well" in the second query, and it's the first one in the first query.

Also, why would you use StringBuilder for your sources_query?

Comment: ResultSet testRs = testPstmt.executeQuery();
if(testRs.next()){
    System.out.println("Result: " + testRs.getString(1));
} after this operation can you call testRs.close() then start second operation. tell me whats happen

Comment: @Goibniu found the issue, give the man a cookie

Comment: @Goibniu, dangit, you're right! I knew it would be something silly like that. Thank you. (And you're right, I don't know why past me chose StringBuilder either.)

Comment: Lol, it can sometimes take a second set of eyes to spot problems :)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using `setString()` entirely, but you may need to use `setInt()` if the column type is not a string for the surrogate key, for example.

Per [prepared statement documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

> **Note:** The setter methods (setShort, setString, and so on) for setting
>   IN parameter values must specify types that are compatible with the
>   defined SQL type of the input parameter. For instance, if the IN
>   parameter has SQL type INTEGER, then the method `setInt` should be
>   used.

Answer (score -2):

Totally off the wall guess (I could be sure if I wrote code to test it, but I'm too lazy):
You call con.prepareStatement() twice on the same connection. I suggest closing the first prepareStatement before getting another prepareStatement from the database. they may be interfering with each other. I would also consider closing  the resultSet too when I'm done with it.
coding suggestion: If you aren't already doing so, I suggest closing a connection, preparedStatement, and resultSet in the finally block of a try/catch/finally, in the reverse order  you obtain them (checking for null before closing each).